# backbone.js model inheritance

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a backbone model

```
var app = app || {};

app.Era = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        from: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        until: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        stash: {
            from: null,
            until: null
        },
        _enabled: true
    },

    toggle: function(){
        if(this.get('_enabled')){
            this.disable();
        }else{
            this.enable();
        }

        this.save();
    },

    enable: function(){
        this.from = this.stash.from;
        this.until = this.stash.until;

        this.stash.from = null; // strictly speaking unnecssary
        this.stash.until = null;

        this._enabled = true;
    },

    disable: function(){
        this.stash.from = this.from;
        this.stash.until = this.until;

        this.from = null;
        this.until = null;

        this._enabled = false;
    },

    enabled: function(){
        return this._enabled;
    },

});
```

which I'm trying to extend like so

```
Name = app.Era.extend({ defaults: { value: '' } });
```

This seems to work, I get no error in the console.
I can even instantiate a new Name, but when I try to instantiate a new Name, I get an Error message:

```
> era = new app.Era()
child
> era.get('from')
-Infinity
> Name = app.Era.extend({ defaults: { value: '' } })
function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
> name = new Name()
child
> name.get('value')
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'
```

I'd be grateful of some feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `name` in that context, you're running into `window.name`.  If you start from scratch without the lowercase name variable you should run just fine.  Also, fencliff makes good points in how to use default inheritance.

Answer (score 10):

***Edit:*** This might very well be a decent answer, but not to this particular question... The correct answer was provided by Bryan Clark. I'll leave this here regardless, because while I misunderstood your question, it describes a solution to a common problem and may help you anyway.

Backbone inheritance works by modifying the constructor function's prototype. When you extend a model and redefine the `defaults` property, it doesn't merge the `Name.defaults` property to `Era.defaults`, but simply hides it.

Consider a simplified example:

```
var Era = Backbone.Model.extend({ name: "Era" });
var Name = Era.extend({ name: "Name" });
console.log(new Name().name); //-> "name", makes sense, right?
```

To merge the derived class `defaults` to the superclass's, you can take advantage of the fact that [`Model.defaults` can be defined as a function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) as well as an object literal.

```
var Era = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
  defaults: {
    //..
  } 
});

var Name = Era.extend({ 
  //define defaults as a function
  defaults: function() {
    //copy the superclass defaults into a new object, and
    //then extend that with the new defaults
    return _.extend({}, Era.prototype.defaults, {
      value:''
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that I read your question poorly. My answer doesn't actually explain why you would be getting the error you are getting in the console. I thought it was a different error. I'll leave this here regardless, and I'll try to pop by later to amend it, if I can think of why you are experiencing that error. Sorry about the confusion!